# Reduce the execution time in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

Here I attached my query. It's getting 60141 ms to execute. I don't know what should i do. But I want to execute in short time.And now I posted my analyze and execute output of my query. Please help on this.

```
EXPLAIN (BUFFERS,ANALYZE) SELECT id 
FROM activitylog 
WHERE (url = '/staff/save/117' OR url = '/staff/create/117') 
AND timestamp > '1990-01-01 00:00:00' 
AND userid IN ( SELECT id 
                FROM users 
                WHERE companyid = ( SELECT companyid 
                                    FROM users 
                                    WHERE id='150' ) ) 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

**Output:**

```
Sort  (cost=934879.83..934879.83 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=63918.947..63918.948 rows=4 loops=1)
    Sort Key: activitylog."timestamp"
    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
    Buffers: shared hit=168161 read=561433
    InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Scan using "usersPrimary" on users users_1  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
       Index Cond: (id = 150)
       Buffers: shared hit=2
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..934871.66 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=63918.693..63918.917 rows=4 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (activitylog.userid = users.id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 400
        Buffers: shared hit=168158 read=561433
    ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..10.53 rows=25 width=4) (actual time=0.018..0.085 rows=101 loops=1)
        Filter: (companyid = $0)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 114
        Buffers: shared hit=10
    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..934860.39 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=120.024..632.858 rows=4 loops=101)
        Buffers: shared hit=168148 read=561433
    ->  Seq Scan on activitylog  (cost=0.00..934860.38 rows=2 width=16) (actual time=12122.376..63918.564 rows=4 loops=1)
        Filter: (("timestamp" > '2019-01-02 19:19:12.649837+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (((url)::text = '/jobs/save/81924'::text) OR ((url)::text = '/jobs/create/81924'::text)))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 11935833
        Buffers: shared hit=168148 read=561433
    Planning time: 0.806 ms
    Execution time: 63919.748 ms
```

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one, Join query will enhance the indexing and optimized query execution time

```
SELECT id
FROM activitylog
WHERE url in ('/staff/save/117','/staff/create/117')
  AND TIMESTAMP > '1990-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1
     FROM users AS u
     JOIN users ur ON ur.CompanyID = u.CompanyID
     WHERE ur.ID = '150'
       AND u.id = activitylog.userid)
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC
```

Comment: I tried it . But It shows error. ` column reference "id" is ambiguous`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried the update one. But no improvement.

Comment: If your activitylog table having millions of records, try lazy loading by processing limited records first. example: page scroller reaches end of the page then show some bunch records.

Comment: It contains millions of records. But the result will be 10 or 15 rows. so we don't need page scroller.

Comment: Good work improving the query. Now all that is left to do is to replace the `IN (SELECT ...)` with an `EXISTS (SELECT ...)` and add the appropriate indexes.

Comment: Oh Great! I learnt it too from http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_exists_clause_vs_in_clause.htm   +1 for your comments @Laurenz albe

Comment: I couldn't replace `IN (SELECT ...)` , If I do like this It shows error.

Comment: Like this syntax error at or near "'/staff/save/117'"

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have updated my answer, Hi Vi j check the code execution time and post me the time taken for it to shows the results.

Comment: @Pranesh Janarthanan I couldn't run your updated code. look here what I got . 

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'/staff/save/117'"
LINE 3: WHERE EXISTS ('/staff/save/117','/staff/create/117')`

Comment: try now, I have updated my code. i have used `IN` for url filter, becuase it has only 2 values. for sub querry with big results to be used with `EXISTS`.

Comment: I did it. Here is the Execution time. `Execution time: 61057.885 ms`

Comment: It shows no improvement, your actual code execution time is `60141 ms` updated query execution time is `61057.885 ms'.

Comment: @Pranesh Janarthanan , current execution time. `Execution time: 63094.763 ms`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Do you have any Idea on this?

Comment: Nobody can tell unless OP adds `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output to the question.

Comment: Let me explain. You run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT /* your query goes here */;`, then you edit your question and add the output. That will contain the answer.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Please see my question. Now I Updated it.

Answer (score 2):

You should rewrite the query using `IN` instead of `OR` like Pranesh Janarthanan's answer suggests, because [`OR` is a performance killer](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/avoid-or-for-better-performance/).

In addition, you need indexes to avoid the expensive sequential scan on `activitylog`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON activitylog (timestamp);
CREATE INDEX ON activitylog (url);
```

Which of these indexes you need depends on how selective the respective conditions are.

Try with each of these indexes and with both (which may give you a “Bitmap And”) and keep what works best.

Comment: We are using activitylog table for many purpose in many controllers. So I am afraid about create indexes. Is it affect other queries in controllers?

Comment: I wasn't aware that Postgres can't rewrite a series of OR conditions to an IN condition to make it more efficient. I will keep that in mind

Comment: @ViJ You are right to be afraid. `activitylog` sounds like something that will receive a lot of `INSERT`s, and that becomes substantially slower with each index. I told you how to make the query fast, you will have to make the balance between query speed and data modification speed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added a link to more of my ramblings on the subject.

Comment: That's a bummer. Even MySQL is able to use the same plan (single index access) in that case.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe How much Index we can use in single table?

Comment: There is no hard limit. The ideal number depends on the queries you need to be fast and the read/write ratio. The more writes on the table, the more indexes will hurt.

Comment: so,Can I use four index in my table?

Comment: You sure *can*. If it will work well for you depends on how many data modifications the table has to undergo.

Comment: Oh well, Thanks. My table holds millions records. Now it is loaded in 1 minute 10 secs. Is It healthy?

Comment: If that is fast enough for you, fine. If not, use fewer indexes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189863/discussion-between-vi-j-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: Already There was two index. Now I added two more indexes. loading speed was 3 minute before I added two index. After added the two index , the speed was reduced by 2 minute.

Comment: For plain inserts, that cannot be. But probably your load process is more complicated.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe can we chat here?. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189863/discussion-between-vi-j-and-laurenz-albe

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe  Now am using like condition in my query. It consumes huge time. Is there any way to replace it?

Comment: Open a new question for that.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I created it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136522/is-there-any-way-to-replace-like-condition-in-postgresql

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure you have the right indexes. Also, let's optimize the query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM activitylog 
WHERE url in ('/staff/save/117', '/staff/create/117') 
AND timestamp > '1990-01-01 00:00:00' 
AND 
(
(userid = 150) or
EXISTS
    (
        select 1
        from users workmate
        join users u150
        on workmate.companyid = u150.companyid and u150.id = 150
        and activitylog.userid = workmate.id
    )
)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: @Vi J try this updated query and post the execution time taken for this. We are waiting eagerly to know the results.

Comment: @Vi J replace it with your actual database column name `userid`. You must have this basic understanding.

Comment: @Pranesh Janarthanan  I did it already in the morning and I ran. There is no improvement on it.It's getting late to retrieve the data

Comment: @ViJ if you get all the ids of workmates of u150 and replace the EXISTS part with userid in (nr1, nr2, ..., nrn), then how is the performance changing?

Comment: @PraneshJanarthanan actually there is still a possibility to improve the query (besides improving the indexes, of course). One could run the equivalent of a subquery to get the ids and then replace the exists part with userid in (nr1, nr2, ..., nrn). This should greatly improve performance, since the set of ids does not depend on the activitylog record.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad It's not working . B'coz It didn't retrive the data what  I expected. And also its take the same time.

Comment: @LajosArpad, i thought of it yesterday, as you said process the subquery and store the results in `#tempResult` and use it as `userid in (select * from #tempResult)`. I wish Mr.ViJ try it post us the execution time.

Comment: @ Pranesh Janarthanan  `Execution time: 73435.822 ms`

Comment: @Vi J Show execution time of partial query: SELECT id 
FROM activitylog 
WHERE url in ('/staff/save/117', '/staff/create/117') 
AND timestamp > '1990-01-01 00:00:00' Also tell what (if any ) indexes did you set for mentioned tables ?