# Is there any way to replace like condition in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, database-performance

I am having the following query in my code. It takes a minute to get the data due to to the `like` condition. If you have any way to replace it or speed up the retrieve time, Please let me know.

```
select id, url
from activitylog
where resource = 'jobs'
  and (method = 'saveTechStatus')
  and (url like '%/jobs/saveTechStatus/81924/%')
order by timestamp desc;
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? replace like condition ?

Comment: I want to reduce the retrieve time.

Comment: What is the type of the url column? Does it have index?

Comment: Did you try creating an index on `(resource, method)`?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. Or upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trigram index:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX ON activitylog USING gin (url gin_trgm_ops);
```

This may take a lot of space, but it can speed up this `LIKE` condition.